# Pandas divide column by index mean

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 index's and I want to divide each value by the column average for the second index (A, B).

For example input df

```
       col1    col2
0 A     1      20
1 A     2      10
2 A     1      10
4 A     4      5
5 B     6      15
6 B     2      50
```

So for col1, I will dived 0A 1A 2A by 2 because the average of 1,2,1,4 is 2.

```
       col1   
0 A     0.5     
1 A     1       
2 A     0.5     
4 A     2      
5 B     1.5     
6 B     0.5
```

Can anyone see a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df.groupby(level=1)['col1'].apply(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

Better without apply is :

```
df.col1/df.groupby(level=1)['col1'].transform('mean')
```

---

**Output**

```
0  A    0.5
1  A    1.0
2  A    0.5
4  A    2.0
5  B    1.5
6  B    0.5
```